# Creation of a table with writings centered both vertically and horizontally

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, tabularx, line

I would like to create a table in which I have all the writings centered, both in row and in column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{<{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{Elenco riassuntivo di tutte le perdite meccaniche}
  \label{Tab:tabellariassuntiva}    
{\centering\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lYYYYY@{}}
    \toprule
 Componente &  Valore & Formulazione utilizzata \\
    \midrule
\thead{Cuscinetto superiore \\ albero verticale U1847} &  650     &   Bearing select SKF \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} to the preamble of your document should result in the expected vertically centered alignment of the contents.

Comment: Why do you declare a total of 6 columns while you only seem to need 3 of them?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your MWE has two errors:

- definition of `Y` column type have wrong sign `<`, it should be `>`
- missing is package `makecell`

and defined to much columns (sufficient are 3 `Y` columns). Considering this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx} % <---
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % <---

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
  \caption{Elenco riassuntivo di tutte le perdite meccaniche}
  \label{Tab:tabellariassuntiva}
\centering\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} YYY @{}} % <---
    \toprule
 Componente &  Valore   & Formulazione utilizzata   \\
    \midrule
\makecell{Cuscinetto superiore\\ albero verticale U1847}
            &  650      &   Bearing select SKF      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

the result of corrected code gives what you after:

[image]

The same result you can obtain with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % <---

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % <---
  \caption{Elenco riassuntivo di tutte le perdite meccaniche}
  \label{Tab:tabellariassuntiva}
\centering\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} YYY @{}}
    \toprule
 Componente &  Valore   & Formulazione utilizzata   \\
    \midrule
Cuscinetto superiore albero verticale U1847
            &  650      &   Bearing select SKF      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```